# Component with setinterval not updating on context state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

**PROBLEM**

When I update the object stored in my ContextProvider I can see all the data update accordingly except for my date countdown.

**DETAILS**

I have a *sidepanel* component that displays data from a list. When a list item is clicked I update the state pf which object is selected in a separate react context. This works fine. An example of what object is stored is below.

**Context Object**

```
{
   "title": "I am the title",
   "startDate" "2021-11-01T02:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I then use this object to render out a sidepanel component with the title and seconds counting down.

**Sidepanel.tsx**

```
export function SidePanel() {
    const { active } = useSidePanel()

    const countdown = useCountdown(new Date(active.startDate))

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{active.title}</h1>
            <p>{countdown} seconds to go</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**useCountdown.tsx**

```
export function useCountdown(date: Date) {
    const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState<number>(0)

    const formatCountdown = () => {
        const diffInSeconds = dateFns.differenceInSeconds(date, new Date())

        if (diffInSeconds <= 1) return 0
        setCountdown(diffInSeconds)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            formatCountdown()
        }, 1000)

        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [])

    return countdown
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So by adding 'date' inside the useEffect array inside *useCountdown.tsx* I was able to solve this problem

```
export function useCountdown(date: Date) {
    ...

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            formatCountdown()
        }, 1000)

        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [date])
   
    ...

}
```

Comment: Yeah you should listen to state changes inside square brackets